# Roku: Thumbnails look pixelated

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

How to fix thumbnail pixelated issue and show like real image?
I am developing (app) channel for Roku using scene graph. 
I created more then one Grid by Markup Grid node and display thumbnail,
the thumbnails look pixelated or stretch.
snapshots of pixelated-grid thumbnail -
[image]

and my [real image is here](http://cdn.vidible.tv/prod/2017-01/12/58781106e809a86a3d72ae5e_o_A_v1.jpg)

Comment: show us snapshots from the screen. what are the exact dimensions of you thumbnails files? to what dimensions do they get re-sized on screen?

Comment: Thank you so much Nas Banov,
I have attached both snapshots (pixelated-grid thumbnail and real image) from the screen.

Comment: capture card under suspicion, see https://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=98638

Comment: The real image and  thumbnails dimensions fulfill on 16:9 ratio. Real image dimension (1920x1080) convert into thumbnails dimensions (230x130) show on the screen .and i do not understand you ask me  "what are the exact dimensions of you thumbnails files" . Please suggestion

Comment: i mean why are the captured images sized 1324x882? Roku has no such display resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your image is not the same aspect ratio you have 2 options.

1. use `loadDisplayMode="scaleToZoom"`
2. give it the desired width and height of the poster size and then use `loadWidth="actual width of pic"` and `loadHeight="actual height of pic"`

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary use the loadDisplayMode as per your requirement, but try setting the loadWidth and loadHeight to the dimensions set for the Poster Component in the RowList. That shall solve the Pixelation problem for you.